# CSS | White spaces in 100% height elements

Tags: html, css

I'm writing here because I've got a problem with CSS. I have a `.container` div that contains another div set to `position:absolute, top:0, left:0` and `width:100%; height:100%`. However I keep seeing these kind of white spaces, that when I zoom in the page disappear. Any solution?

```css
.loop {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 36px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 250px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background 0.2s;
}

.goPrev,
.goNext {
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.goMid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 36px;
  width: calc(100% - 72px);
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  padding-top: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.goMid:hover,
.goPrev:hover,
.goNext:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="loop">
    <div class="goPrev">
    </div>
    <div class="goMid">
      Help me.
    </div>
    <div class="goNext">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

That is just a draw.

[Here you have the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD1Kb.png)

Comment: Please share a [mcve]

Comment: This looks Chrome-specific as I cannot see the gap on Firefox.

Comment: I don't see it in chrome, edge, or firefox, zoomed in or normal...

Comment: Does it still happen if you remove the `transform: translateX(-50%)`? I think sometimes those can be a little inexact... Just kindof stabbing in the dark...

Comment: I can't see the issue in the image in the code you have. Do you see it when you run that snippet? If so, you may need to include details of your browser/OS/screen size and any other information you can think of that might affect your display.

Comment: Ok, I *can* see it in chrome, but only when zoomed in 67 - 75%. If I zoom in or out it goes away. Is this what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not totally sure what to do, but the following changes seem to fix the problem for me. I changed:

- Set `.loop` `overflow` from `hidden` to `visible`
- Set `.goMid` `top` from `0` to `-1px`
- The `.goMid` `height` from `100%` to `calc(100% + 2px)`

When I moved the inner div underneath the border using `top: -5px` I still saw the whitespace until I changed the outer div overflow property to `visible`. Then if you stretch the inner div a little it seems to solve the problem. It helps that your outer div has a thick border.

```css
.loop {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 36px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 250px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* HERE */
  overflow: visible;
  transition: background 0.2s;
}

.goPrev,
.goNext {
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.goMid {
  position: absolute;
  /* HERE */
  top: -1px;
  left: 36px;
  width: calc(100% - 72px);
  /* HERE */
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  font-family: "Poppins";
  padding-top: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.goMid:hover,
.goPrev:hover,
.goNext:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="loop">
    <div class="goPrev">
    </div>
    <div class="goMid">
      Help me.
    </div>
    <div class="goNext">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

For what it's worth, I think @MarkP may have a good point. Combining absolute positioning and flexbox does feel like maybe a code smell. But, I don't know what the context is in your code and my flexbox-fu is a little shaky.

Answer (score 0):

**ACTUAL GENERATED VIEW**:

I added text to all 3 nested divs and got the following centered display.

[image]

You can see all your text is bunched together. I am going to review your code and the offer a way forward. You may find you need to re-word your problem to allow us to help you better. My assumption is you are trying to set-up a tool to navigate through some type of media, such as images or pages.

**CODE REVIEW**

In review of your Code i can see you are trying to use a 3 part display using flexbox. Except you have also included absolute positions which prevents relative display of the divs alongside each other. Now i know you are concerned about white space but i am going to suggest a way to better use flex-box as well as debugging the whitespace, although it would be better to start again with a appropriate flexbox structure.

**WHITE SPACE DEGUGGING**

My suggestion first would be to remove CSS that could be causing this and then re-introduce the CSS progressively. If you are using Google Chrome you can use the insight tool to adjust the live CSS. Simply right-click on the area you wish to inspect and the CSS being used there will be displayed. *You can edit directly in the CSS display and it will change the page behaviour, this is great for debugging and seeing what CSS improves your layout. Once you find the CSS you need you can replicate that in your code.*

I would start with removing the following and see how you go:

- Remove `overflow:hidden;`

When you look closer you can see the style code allows for 36px for each div on the left and the right. There may be an image missing from the .goPrev and .goNext divs, where your white space is now. Not sure if you copied your code from somewhere or wrote this from scratch?

**TRY STARTING WITH A NEW FLEX-BOX STRUCTURE**

I recommend creating your divs from scratch using one of the approaches found here: [Common CSS Flexbox Layout Patterns with Example Code](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/common-flexbox-patterns/) . Flexbox is super simple and a great way to build mobile responsive layouts.